# Not able to run Visual Studio 2015 Angular 2 QuickStart

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, angular

I am trying to run Angular2 quickstart application with Visual Studio 2015 community edition. For this, I am following this link - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/visual-studio-2015.html

However, while building application I am getting typescript related errors. Refer below screenshot. Does anyone knows what I am missing here?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EgVv.png)

In Error List, I get these 2 errors-

> Your project file uses a different version of the TypeScript compiler
>   and tools than is currently installed on this machine.  No compiler
>   was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe.  You may be able to fix this problem by
>   changing the  element in your project file.
>
> The specified task executable location "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe" is invalid.

After investigation, I found that, there is no tsc.exe in "C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\" folder.

Another point is,  is having value as 1.8

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

> **My Environment:**
>
> Angular 2 version RC2
>
> Typescript version 1.8
>
> Visual Studio 2015 Community edition

Thanks

Comment: do you have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\ folder?

Comment: Duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594894/no-typescript-compiler-was-found-at-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-sdks-typesc

Comment: yes @Vitaliy...I have C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\ folder

Comment: @AngJobs As per that link, I have already tried reinstalling typescript tools for VS2015 but no luck. I dont see tsc.exe.

Comment: install nuget packages Microsoft.TypeScript.Compiler and Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild

Comment: @JaimeStill thanks! will try this.