# Typescript won't install into C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript'

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, tsc

My issue *might* be related to this one: [No TypeScript compiler was found at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.8\tsc.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36594894/no-typescript-compiler-was-found-at-c-program-files-x86-microsoft-sdks-typesc) but I want to ask a different question.

When trying to install Typescript (currently 1.8.36) into Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, I don't see it installed into the Microsoft SDKs\Typescript folder.  I'm pulling the install packages from http://www.typescriptlang.org, but I can't determine where the compiler gets installed and using 'where tsc' in Cmd isn't showing me anything useful.  I know the latest releases of VS include TS, but they only go up to 1.8.10, and besides when trying to build my solution I get the issue I linked to, so something isn't right.

I've removed Productivity Tools and Web Essentials from both VS 2013 and 2015 and reinstalled TS but no luck.

So my question is how do I install the Typescript compiler into VS 2013 Update 5 or VS 2015 Update 3 such that MSBuild will find something at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\(TypescriptVersion) and compile my solution?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, the Typescript in SDKs directory comes once you install the extension into any version of Visual Studio. So to install Typescript version 1.8 do the following:

- Open Visual studio
- Click on Tools > Extensions and Updates
- On the left side select, Online group
- Search *typescript*
- From the results select your desired version (in your case 1.8)
- Click install, it will download a small web installer
- Close the VS instance, and install the extension
- Open your solution and try to build now

This should work just fine.