# tsc.exe not found in fresh visual studio 2017 using cordova

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2017

I get an error while trying to compile a cordova app in a newly installed visual studio 2017 on windows 10 (The previous Visual Studio 2015 is still installed).

The error code is MSB6001 (Sorry, German). The English translation: invalid command line option "tsc.exe". The value is not allowed to be NULL. Parametername: path1

[image: Error for missing tsc.exe in path1. The value is not allowed to be NULL]

I tried to google the problem. This is an issue with TypeScript. It seems that visual studio does not find the correct version (or any at all).

[Michael Samteladze postet a solution where the correct TypeScript Version is written in the .jsproj file.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/211619/view.html) [This is the same solution silver server proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36606851/2381164). However this does not help. There are some old discussions on [github](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2039) regarding older versions of visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me:

Set the parameter

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion Condition="'$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)'==''">2.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

in file C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets to the correct TypeScript Version (in my case 2.8) and Cordova can finally compile.